# Javascipt:void(0) but no onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick

While searching for something, came across this article and have no idea how the below code works:

```
<a class="button eula-download-button" data-g-event="cta" data-g-label="download-chrome" 
    href="javascript:void(0)">Download Chrome</a>
```

this page uses it:
https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/

This blog discusses it:
http://adactio.com/journal/6022/

My question is, if there is no onClick, how is the action done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a "listener" to fire when you click the `<a>` where the "listener" is active.

For example:

```
var el = document.getElementById("t"); 
el.addEventListener("click", function(){...runcode... }, false);
```

This will run a function when you click in the element with the ID name "t"

**In this case** the button uses classes, so it could look like this in plain javascript:

```
var el = document.querySelector("eula-download-button"); 
el.addEventListener("click", function(){...runcode... }, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

In vanilla JS, you can use:

[addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/elemento.addEventListener)

Answer (score 1):

perhaps there's something like  in jQuery:
`$(".link_class").on("click",function(){
     // some action
});`